# Navbar styling issue

Tags: html, css, navbar

Using a centred logo in between the menu bar, I noticed that on Internet Explorer, the logo was out of place slightly. I added a custom css (custom.css) document to fix the logo-menu placement for all browsers, but the result has affecting the navbar for mobile viewing. 
How can I adapt my custom.css or regular code so the menu fits properly for all browsers, but mobile navbar is still unaffected.

This is the live link:
http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/index.html

This is the custom.css I have tried (seen in Head)

```css
/* custom css for sunplay */


header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar {
    display: flex;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .mainbar-row {
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center !important;
    margin: 0;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto .navbar-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.lqd-css-sticky-wrap .ld-parallax-wrap.parallax-applied span.split-inner, .ld-parallax-wrap.parallax-applied span.split-inner {
    transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}


@media(max-width: 480px){
.ld-parallax-wrap .lqd-lines.split-unit .split-inner{
 font-size: 53px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#3ed2a7">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png" />

        <title>Sun play</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/yza0jhh.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/liquid-icon/liquid-icon.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/brands.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/solid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/theme-vendors.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/theme.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/themes/restaurant.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/custom.css" />
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <!-- Head Libs -->


    </head>
    <body data-mobile-nav-trigger-alignment="right" data-mobile-nav-align="left" data-mobile-nav-style="classic" data-mobile-nav-shceme="gray" data-mobile-header-scheme="gray" data-mobile-nav-breakpoint="1199">

        <div id="wrap">

            <header class="main-header main-header-overlay">

                <div class="mainbar-wrap">
                    <div class="megamenu-hover-bg"></div><!-- /.megamenu-hover-bg -->
                    <div class="container mainbar-container">
                        <div class="mainbar">
                            <div class="row mainbar-row align-items-lg-stretch">



                                <div class="col-auto">

                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-header-collapse">

                                        <ul id="primary-nav" class="main-nav nav main-nav-hover-fade-inactive align-items-lg-stretch justify-content-lg-start" data-submenu-options='{ "toggleType":"fade", "handler":"mouse-in-out" }'>

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="index.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Home
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="about.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            About Us
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Services
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                                <ul class="nav-item-children">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="property.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Property Management
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="leasing.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Leasing
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="leasing2.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Resale
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="concierge.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Concierge
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>


                                                </ul>
                                            </li>




                                        </ul><!-- /#primary-nav  -->

                                    </div><!-- /#main-header-collapse -->

                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" rel="home">
                                            <span class="navbar-brand-inner">
                                                <img class="mobile-logo-default" src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png" srcset="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png 1x" alt="Ave HTML Template">
                                                <img class="logo-default" src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png" srcset="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png 1x" alt="Ave HTML Template">
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed nav-trigger style-mobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-header-collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-changeclassnames='{ "html": "mobile-nav-activated overflow-hidden" }'>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="bars">
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->

                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-header-collapse">

                                        <ul id="primary-nav" class="main-nav nav main-nav-hover-fade-inactive align-items-lg-stretch justify-content-lg-start" data-submenu-options='{ "toggleType":"fade", "handler":"mouse-in-out" }'>

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="restaurant.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Dining
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="fitness.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Fitness
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="membership.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Memberships
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>





                                        </ul><!-- /#primary-nav  -->

                                    </div><!-- /#main-header-collapse -->

                                </div><!-- /.col -->



                            </div><!-- /.mainbar-row -->
                        </div><!-- /.mainbar -->
                    </div><!-- /.mainbar-container -->
                </div><!-- /.mainbar-wrap -->

            </header><!-- /.main-header -->

            <main id="content" class="content">

                <section
                    class="vc_row lqd-css-sticky bg-cover bg-center fullheight d-flex align-items-center py-5"
                    data-parallax="true"
                    data-parallax-options='{"parallaxBG":true}'
                    data-slideshow-bg="true"
                    data-slideshow-options='{"delay":2500,"imageArray":["http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide1_index.jpg","http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide2_index.jpg","http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide3_index.jpg"]}'>

                    <span class="row-bg-loader"></span>

                    <div class="liquid-row-overlay bg-black opacity-03"></div>

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="lqd-space" style="height: 180px;"></div>

                            <div
                                class="lqd-column col-md-12 text-center px-lg-12" 
                                data-custom-animations="true"
                                data-ca-options='{"triggerHandler":"inview", "animationTarget":"all-childs", "duration":1600, "delay":250, "easing":"easeOutQuint", "direction":"forward", "initValues":{"opacity":0, "translateY":800 }, "animations":{"opacity":1, "translateY":-97}}'
                                data-parallax="true"
                                data-parallax-from='{"translateY":1}'
                                data-parallax-to='{"translateY":-150}'
                                data-parallax-options='{"easing":"linear","reverse":true,"triggerHook":"onEnter", "overflowHidden": false}'>


                                <h2
                                    class="mt-70 mb-70 text-white lh-115" style="margin-bottom: 200px;"
                                    data-fittext="true"
                                    data-fittext-options='{"compressor":0.75,"maxFontSize":"64","minFontSize":"48"}'
                                    data-split-text="true"
                                    data-split-options='{"type":"lines"}'>
                                    Sunplay Club Bangsaray  </h2>
                                <!-- <br> excutive summary</h2>
                            <a
                                href="#"
                                class="btn btn-solid text-uppercase btn-lg border-thin btn-white py-1 px-2"
                                data-localscroll="true"
                                data-localscroll-options='{"scrollBelowSection":true}'>
                                <span>
                                    <span class="btn-txt">TEXT</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="lqd-space" style="height: 120px;"></div>

                            <p
                                class="text-uppercase text-white font-size-12 ltr-sp-3"
                                data-split-text="true"
                                data-split-options='{"type":"lines"}'>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
                                <a class="text-white" href="#">find us at</a>
                            </p>

                        </div><!-- /.lqd-column col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 -->

                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                             </section>

            </footer><!-- /.main-footer -->

        </div><!-- /#wrap -->



       
       

       <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/theme-vendors.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/theme.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/liquidAjaxMailchimp.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @P.Sav, How does it look for you in IE currently? (Can you add screenshot?) Also what are you expecting it must be look for IE?

Comment: Can you please add more of what is the real issue? Something like :1.) https://i.imgur.com/9QcgCGN.png 2) https://i.imgur.com/racK73E.png

Comment: Now IE & Chrome browser looks fine, but if you look in mobile (chrome) there is a serious styling issue caused by the custom.css i added- https://imgur.com/a/2es446u

Comment: This is what it looks: https://i.imgur.com/N9DRvSz.png  for me. What are you expecting for it to look?

Comment: The white gaps either side of the navbar (mobile) look awful. It should be the same colour of blue even when expanded. It was fine prior to adding the custom css which resolved the logo issue but created this. You cans see the result if you remove custom.css altogether, the mobile navbar looks great.